# Smaller page margins with figure containing listings

Tags: floats, listings, margins, minipage

I have been trying to get this working for a while, but have been unable to find the appropriate solution which looks good. The idea is that I want to have a single line of three listings. I do this by having a figure which contains three minipages which each contain a listing.

A MWE is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
    \centering
\begin{minipage}[t]{.30\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={a}]
for (i in 1..n):
  . . .
  lock.lock()
  shared++
  lock.unlock()
  . . .
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.30\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={b}]
for (i in 1..n):
  . . .
  lock.lock()
  shared++
  lock.unlock()
  . . .
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.30\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={c}]
for (i in 1..n):
  . . .
  lock.lock()
  shared++
  lock.unlock()
  . . .
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This places all three listings on a single row. However, I would like each listing to be wider and the figure to stretch over the margins of the page.

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `minipage`s in a `tabular` and increase their width.

You'll have a warning `Overfull \hbox` but, in this case, is wanted.

To begin before the left margin put a `\hspace*{-...}` before your `tabular`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{showframe}% only to show the page margins
\usepackage{mwe}% only to have some blind text
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}
\hspace*{-100pt}% to go to the left of the left margin 
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.3\paperwidth}% increase the width according to your needs
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={a}]
for (i in 1..n):
  . . .
  lock.lock()
  shared++
  lock.unlock()
  . . .
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[t]{.3\paperwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={b}]
for (i in 1..n):
  . . .
  lock.lock()
  shared++
  lock.unlock()
  . . .
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[t]{.3\paperwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={c}]
for (i in 1..n):
  . . .
  lock.lock()
  shared++
  lock.unlock()
  . . .
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that using "frame" in the lstlisting settings breaks this. That is for example, \begin{lstlisting}[frame=single, caption={a}]. :-(

Comment: @Andreas It's better you ask a follow-up question, unfortunately, I'm not an expert...