# Adding frame to listing breaks document

Tags: tables, listings, minipage

This is a follow-up question of [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/355951/101651), the solution given there - which places three listings in a single row, extending outside of the margins of the page (desirable in this case) - breaks when styling in the form of a frame to the listings is added, for example:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single, caption={a}]
```

Is it possible to solve this without involving complex tikz-drawings?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{showframe}% only to show the page margins
\usepackage{mwe}% only to have some blind text
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}
\hspace*{-100pt}% to go to the left of the left margin 
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.3\paperwidth}% increase the width according to your needs
\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single, caption={a}]
for (i in 1..n):
  . . .
  lock.lock()
  shared++
  lock.unlock()
  . . .
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[t]{.3\paperwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={b}]
for (i in 1..n):
  . . .
  lock.lock()
  shared++
  lock.unlock()
  . . .
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[t]{.3\paperwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={c}]
for (i in 1..n):
  . . .
  lock.lock()
  shared++
  lock.unlock()
  . . .
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Add `\lstset{frame=single}` to your preamble.

Comment: @Bobyandbob I'd add: "... and leave `\begin{lstlisting}[caption={a}]` unchanged". Please transform your comment into an answer because it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `\lstset{frame=single}` to your preamble and maybe you have to change `\hspace*{}`.

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{showframe}% only to show the page margins
\usepackage{mwe}% only to have some blind text

\lstset{frame=single}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}
\hspace*{-120pt}% to go to the left of the left margin 
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.3\paperwidth}% increase the width according to your needs
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={a}]
for (i in 1..n):
  . . .
  lock.lock()
  shared++
  lock.unlock()
  . . .
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[t]{.3\paperwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={b}]
for (i in 1..n):
  . . .
  lock.lock()
  shared++
  lock.unlock()
  . . .
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[t]{.3\paperwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={c}]
for (i in 1..n):
  . . .
  lock.lock()
  shared++
  lock.unlock()
  . . .
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```